# Save and Read Image from documents folder Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, save

I saved an image in the documents directory, but when I tried to read it, it appears that the file wasnt saved at all.
The read path is OK, the same as the save one.

```
[_IDBanners addObject:@"44"];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
            NSString * name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[_IDBanners objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name]; //Add the file name

            NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
```

When I log:

```
NSLog(@"%@",image);
```

it returns (null).

Comment: Look at the value of `filePath`. Is there really an image at that path?

Comment: Yes, all the images are there

Comment: That's not what I asked. In this specific case, is the value of `filePath` correct? Does it exactly match (case sensitive and all) the full path of an actual image file? The code looks right. So make sure this exact file actually exists. BTW - why load the data then the image? Why not use `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:`?

Comment: Yes, just copy and pasted the filePath in finder, and it goes exactly to the image.